# Oak leaves turn white

Tags: leaves, pests, oak

My oak sapling was doing well all summer, until a few weeks ago. It has these leaves that turn white. I removed one branch with white leaves already but it still seems to 'spread'. Anyone know what it is? Is it lethal or harmless?
[image: Oak]

Comment: How is your sapling doing these days?  Did it survive?

Comment: @MackM, Yes the plant survived :-) and the next year the white leaves did not come back. Just some temporarily inconvenience I guess...

Answer (score -2):

That’s because the leaves have ammonium nitrate due to high carbon concentration in air. How good is your ventilation ?

Comment: Welcome.  I haven't heard of this, do you have a citation/reference for it

Comment: Sounds like bogus, carbon has nothing to do with ammonium nitrate. And concentration of carbon? Do you mean that black powder?? The plant is outside, ventilation all over...